# Display/ Edit Any Xml in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a situation where my users want to view xml, edit it, and then submit the page in the ASP.NET MVC 4 App.

I have looked across many different places, and found that the solution to this question did most of the work for me, but it doesn't allow any editing of the Xml. It just shows the whole xml document. => [Displaying / editing xml in an MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426048/displaying-editing-xml-in-an-mvc-app)

Ideally, what I would like to have happen is that each node with data has a text box with that data in it when the page loads. I want the user to be able to look through the document, change any of the values they want, then click the submit button where I will perform operations on the edited xml. There shouldn't be any node attributes to deal with.

Based on the above link, I did this =>

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult XmlEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        string model = "<Xml><RAY>rayTheMan</RAY><BROTHER><JOHN>JohnAintSoGreat</JOHN></BROTHER></Xml>"; 
        //My logic for the dynamic xml hasn't been made yet.
        //Haven't done POST logic yet.

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(model);

        ViewData["XmlData"] = doc.ToString();

        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <pre style="font-size: 15px;"><code>@ViewData["XmlData"]</code></pre>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="POST" />
    </div>

}
```

Is this even possible? I can't NECESSARILY use a ViewModel since the xml that the page will generate will be of many different schemas. If there is a way to do this with a ViewModel, I'm open to it.

Here is an example of the kind of xml files that my page would accept. There should be editable textboxes placed at the "rayTheMan" and "JohnAintSoGreat" values.

```
<Xml>
  <RAY>rayTheMan</RAY>
  <SIBLING>
    <JOHN>JohnAintSoGreat</JOHN>
  </SIBLING>
</Xml>
```

Please help! :(

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with view model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string DataHtml { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
<div>     
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.DataHtml);
</div>
```

controller:

```
return View(new MyModel() { DataHtml = "<Xml><RAY>rayTheMan</RAY><BROTHER><JOHN>JohnAintSoGreat</JOHN></BROTHER></Xml>" });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just render all of the Xml in a textbox/area? I don't think I want to allow users to change nodes or break a valid Xml.

Comment: I just verified the code: This solution does not get the results I am looking for. It is a solution I'll use if I am forced to get something out there, but it's not the ideal I'm looking for.

Comment: @EternalLearner you can try to make some server side validation which will compare xml (with text content excluded between ><) with the modified version. This way you can check if the user break your xml.